# xcodebuild archive success on Terminal but not on Jenkins

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, xcode9

I have problem when execute command line on Jenkins

> xcodebuild -workspace AhaFastlane.xcworkspace -scheme Pro -sdk iphoneos -configuration AppStoreDistribution archive -archivePath $PWD/builds/AhaFastlane.xcarchive

this command execute successfully on terminal but failed on Jenkins, although passing clean and build commands.

Here is my error:
[image]

Comment: Make sure you set keychain cert codesign settings to always trust. try using -allowProvisioningUpdates argument if you are using automatic code signing. If you are using manual code signing make sure your developer certificate is added to keychain and provisioning profile is downloaded and added in /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles and finally add unlock key chain command before xcodebuild to allow keychain access to Xcode build security unlock-keychain -p "your_system_password" ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db && xcodebuild -......

Comment: You can read all you need to know about setting up Jenkins with Xcode here https://learnwithmehere.blogspot.in/2017/12/one-stop-solution-for-setting-up-ci-and.html

Comment: error is clear, Jenkins could not access your code sign certificates. Either they are not available in Jenkins login keychain db or you have not set access control to your certs in keychain